# Error: mdb_env_open: No such file or directory BLAST+ local database problem

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics

So I'm following the NCBI instructions available here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK52640/

and I can't for the life of me understand what's wrong here.

Here's my PATH and BLASTDB:
[image: path and blastdb]

And the error message: 
[image: Error message]

And my blastdb directory:
[image]

And here's my Python code:

```
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbipsiblastCommandline
import subprocess


psi_cline = NcbipsiblastCommandline('psiblast', db = 'refseq_protein.00',\
                                        query = "results.fasta", evalue =  10 , \
                                        out = "out_psi.xml", outfmt = 7, \
                                        out_pssm ="pssm-results_pssm")

print(psi_cline)
```

Comment: Have you set your environmental variables per the the instructions you cite? Not finding the file directory may mean it does not know where to look because there is either no, or an incorrect ENV setting

Comment: the call may be referencing http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/starting.html  which may be a reasonable store used within the blast software but should not be any of your concern as a user ...  nor should it be a python requirement issue although that is conceivable ...

Comment: there is a brand new version out in the last two weeks --  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK131777/#Blast_ReleaseNotes.BLAST_2_10_0_December

Comment: peeking at their code they are using lmdb and it do see signs of recent improvements ... e.g. `c++/src/util/lmdbxx/lmdb++.h.orig `  which may all just be a long winded way to say maybe it is not your fault and not understanding it is good. means you are paying attention

Answer (score 2):

I had this very problem today and it turns out that my blast-database was corrupted in some manner. I recreated my database with makeblastdb and this error went away.